# How to avoid name conflicts in BDD (lettuce)

Tags: namespaces, bdd, lettuce

I'm twiddling with lettuce to learn BDD in Django while I think of a situation where two steps in different scenarios happen to have same name, e.g.,

```
Feature: a feature A
    Scenario: a scenario S1
        Given this is the conflicted step
        Then chect the result of scenario S1

Feature: a feature B
    Scenario: a scenario S2
        Given this is the conflicted step
        Then chect the result of scenario S2
```

The above step ***this is the conflicted step*** happened to be defined in multiple scenarios with different meaning. Then the test code below for this step will executed for all the occurrences of this step.

```
@step(r'this is the conflicted step')
def mytest(step):
    # do test
```

My question is, is there a kind of namespace mechanism which allow us create different test code for steps with same name but in different scenarios ? e.g., I expect the following test codes or something like them:

```
@step(r'a feature A', r'this is the conflicted step')
def aaaa(step):
    # do test

@step(r'a feature B', r'this is the conflicted step')
def bbbb(step):
    # do other test
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with lettuce, but in Cucumber you have the noition of a [`Background`](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/background).

Using a `Background`, you can define a shared "given" step for all the scenarios, thus you could then remove the conflicting step.

If this isn't what you need, then you will have to change the text of the steps, to be more specific about what they do, in order to remove the conflict.